# Jack for long-barrel plug

Tags: cables, plug

I have a DC power cable that ends in a 5.5 x 2.5 mm plug. I purchased a panel mount jack for it, and yes, the plug fits. However, the barrel is much longer than the jack, so the barrel does not fit flush, which seems like a bad idea.

The barrel length is about 12 mm.

The panel mount jacks I see online seem similar to the one I have. How do I find one (a spec or search term) that will have the right depth?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for 5.5x2.1mm jack dimensions offered a [Mouser parametric search](https://www.mouser.ie/Connectors/Power-Connectors/DC-Power-Connectors/_/N-axitt?P=1z0wxf2Z1z0wxfc) for DC power plugs.

A search for DC barrel jack brought me to Wikipedia's [Coaxial power connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector).

I seem to remember buying 14 mm long jacks for one project. (The socket was already in the device to be powered.)